# Удалить Item через ListView(выделение Item) в firebase

Tags: java, android

Вывожу свою базу данных в ListView.
Скажите как удалить определенный Item через ListView(методом выделение Item) из firebase....

получаю данные так:

```html
private ArrayList<String> keylist = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList <ClientModel> user = new ArrayList<>();

DatabaseReference rootRef1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        DatabaseReference uidRef1 = rootRef1.child("Markers").child(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
        uidRef1.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
        
                Double latitude = dataSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue(Double.class);
                Double longitude = dataSnapshot.child("longitude").getValue(Double.class);
               
                ClientModel data1 = dataSnapshot.getValue(ClientModel.class);
                             keylist.add(key);
                             user.add(data1);
                             adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });

    }
```

что писать в Listview ???

```
listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, final int position, long arg3) {

            
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Сначала получаете выделенный элемент. Соответственно того класса, которым у Вас представляются элементы Вашего списка, для примера - String. Или потом из полученного элемента вытягиваете id или нужные атрибуты.

```
final String itemToDelete = (String)listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

Затем при желании (ну и желательно) добавить AlertDialog, где можно было бы подтвердить/отменить удаление, например, так:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this);
builder.setTitle("Вы точно хотите удалить этот элемент?");
builder.setPositiveButton("Да", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
           try{
               yourDatabaseReference.child(itemToDelete).removeValue(); 
           } catch (Exception e){}
        }
});
builder.setNegativeButton("Нет", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
});
builder.show();
```

Надеюсь, это Вам поможет.